# Advice on SQL query for finding records that are included in a range of epoch times

Tags: sql, timestamp, where-clause, epoch, postgresql-9.5

**EDITED to include a 'CREATE TABLE' script for those that need less abstraction (see bottom of question)**

Working a water management alarm system where the hardware runs a scheduled timer 'program' that contains start/stop times, and each program may run one or more 'stations' (valves or sprinklers or whatever) that run with their own start/stop times controlled by the 'program'.  See the block below for a rough example, followed by an explanation.

```
|<---- Program 1 ----------------------------------------------->|
|<-- Station 1 -->|   |<---- Station 2 ---->|<---- Station 3 --->|

|<---- Program 2 ---------------------------------------->|
          |<---- Station 4 ---->|<---- Station 5 -->|

|<---- Program 3 --->|
|<---- Station 6 -->|

                                |<-- Master Pump Fail Alarm -->|
```

In the above 'pseudo schedule', Program 1 has 3 stations running and Program 2 has 2 stations running.  Program 3 has one station. A master pump fails exactly when Station 5 in Program 2 starts, but the alarm ends (maybe got fixed?) after Program 2 ends but still within the run time of Program 1.  Arrows indicate start and stop times and range of the event's running time.

Basically, I'm trying to suss out a WHERE clause algorithm along the lines of something like:

```
SELECT stuff WHERE "a program's or station's running time occurred *during* the alarm period (alarm.begintime to alarm.endtime in the schema below)".
```

The result for that using the above example schedule should return a list of records that includes Program 1 with Stations 2 and 3, and Program 2 with only Station 5.

The start and end times for Programs, Stations and Alarms are recorded in the database in EPOCH/UNIXTIME.  Database engine is PostgreSQL 9.6.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.

If something needs more clarification, please ask.  Thanks in advance for any tidbits to help solve the problem.

Schema below *should* create a similar layout to the visualization block above:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
 oid PRIMARY KEY,
 itemid INTEGER,
 itemtype VARCHAR (255),
 begintime INTEGER,
 endtime INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 1, 'Program', 1556809522, 1556809680);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 1, 'Station', 1556809522, 1556809560);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, 2, 'Station', 1556809620, 1556809642);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (4, 3, 'Station', 1556809642, 1556809680);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (5, 2, 'Program', 1556809522, 1556809670);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (6, 4, 'Station', 1556809541, 1556809630);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (7, 5, 'Station', 1556809630, 1556809660);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (8, 3, 'Program', 1556809522, 1556809618);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (9, 6, 'Station', 1556809522, 1556809617);

INSERT INTO test VALUES (10, 1, 'Alarm', 1556809630, 1556809675);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the `create table` statements for the involved tables ([formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: I'd rather not add 'create table' as it detracts from the question and is not relevant.  There never were any screenshots in my post.

Comment: We need to know the columns and their data types of the tables involved. What are the names of the tables? Is the alarm time a single column or a start/end column? What are the foreign columns in the tables that can be used to join them? A little SQL script  that sets up a [self contained example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) would help those people trying to help you as they can then try out their solution before posting it.

Comment: You are probably looking for the `overlaps` operator or a range type (which would be easier to use with proper `timestamp` columns, but can probably made to work with a epoch as well)

Comment: I believe I did that with '...The start and end times for Programs, Stations and Alarms are recorded in the database in EPOCH/UNIXTIME...'.   The exact column names are less important than determining how to find records that are included within a range of epoch time (the alarm time in this case).  Not sure how a script will solve that, but ok, will see what I can whip together.

Comment: updated to include a hopefully working script for those that need to beat on real data to try out solutions.  Good luck, and thanks for your time and insights.